# Joomla link to category

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I've a custom module with some href that  refer to a single article like this:

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=5&amp;Itemid=473">
```

or

```
<a href="index.php/9-articles/7-sport">
```

When I click on link,the relative article is showed, but I would refer to a category ,as I can see all the articles into the category how can I do that?

Comment: so you want to link to a page that shows all the articles in that category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is that you can create new menu then new menu item of type category( NOTE that **do not Associate this menu to any module position** so it is hidden ) then use link created for than menu item anywhere you want